# The fastest way to set the focus on a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, setfocus

what is the fastest (the really fastest) way to set the focus on a textfield?

**My page looks like**

```
<html>
 <head> ... </head>

  <body>

    ... content ...  

    <input type="text" id="ct_one" name="ct_pet[]" value="" />

    ... content ...

   <script> ... load jquery and jquery_ui ... </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a script right after the element, that sets focus to it. That would set focus at the earliest possible moment, i.e. right after the element is created.

```
<input type="text" id="ct_one" name="ct_pet[]" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('ct_one').focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign value 0 to attribute tabindex for your input field.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex

Comment: That will only place it first in the tab order, it won't focus it.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. It doesn't get focus and with value "0" field won't even be first in tab order. Instead it will be last in order of elements with "tabindex" set. I should had checked it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer here seems to be "the really fastest" :)

[**Set input field focus on start typing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840407/set-input-field-focus-on-start-typing)

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/4T6Q5/)